# Text color doesn't change when hovered, but others do

Tags: html, css

On my website, http://thelooter.family, I've got the following CSS code:

```
#nav a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#nav a:visited {
    color: lime;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a {
    color: lime;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav #location {
    color: skyblue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and the following HTML code:

```
<div id="nav">
  <p>
    <a href="/#" id="location">Home</a><br>
    <a href="/gamecheatlist">Game Cheat List</a><br>
    <img src="" id="2big4u" height="10px" width="10px"/>&nbsp;
    <a href="/gamecheatlist/minecraft">Minecraft</a><br>
    <img src="" id="2big4u" height="10px" width="10px"/>&nbsp;
    <img src="" id="2big4u" height="10px" width="10px"/>&nbsp;
    <a href="/gamecheatlist/minecraft/crafting">Crafting</a><br>
    <img src="" id="2big4u" height="10px" width="10px"/>&nbsp;
    <a href="/gamecheatlist/little-alchemy">Little Alchemy</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

The links, when hovered should turn red, right? When hovering on Minecraft, Crafting, or Little Alchemy, they turn red, but Game Cheat List stays lime.

Comment: I don't see any problems base on your given link, all links when hover, make its color to red.

Comment: Its turning red on hover : http://prnt.sc/akxw7h . Whats the issue?

Comment: @TheUknown it breaks once the link has been visited. That's the problem

Comment: @4castle I posted an answer. EDIT: Oh nevremind, you did too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies here:

```
#nav a:visited {
    color: lime;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Once the link is visited, it doesnt turn red on hover.

Apply these css changes and it should work fine:

```
 #nav a:hover, #nav a:visited:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Check this screenshot](http://prntscr.com/akxxxr)

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for. Changes have been made.

Answer (score 1):

It stays lime green because you have visited the link, and your CSS selectors for `a:hover` and `a:visited` are equally "strong", therefore the last selector wins out. To fix it, **reorder your CSS selectors** by declaring `a:hover` *after* `a:visited` so that `a:hover` is stronger than `a:visited`, or increase the specificity of `a:hover`.

```
#nav a:visited {
    color: lime;
    text-decoration: none;
}    
#nav a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[A Quick Guide to CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: This works. I always prefer adding specific rules. (Its like finding a bug) if OP had added in order, he wouldnt face this issue. If in future some other dev makes a change and moves code around, it difficult to figure out what caused it to break. Just saying, nothing wrong with the solution

Comment: @TheUknown I agree. I like your solution better for maintainability.

Comment: @TheUknown However, my solution explains and corrects the actual source of the problem.

Comment: Oh yeah, absolutely. Like I said nothing wrong with your solution, I was just discussing in terms of maintainability.